# How can I disable skipFiles in VS Code's JavaScript debug terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, javascript-debugger

How can VS Code's JavaScript Debug Terminal be coerced into stepping into node's internal JavaScript files (Ex. the `http` module to step into the `createServer` function, for example)? There are many questions and answers about how to skip node internal files, but my question is the opposite.

I've tried:

- ```json
  "debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "skipFiles": [
      "<node_internals>/**/*.cc"
    ]
  },
  ```

  (I know the VS Code debugger can't jump into c++ code, so I just tried this in hopes that the .js files wouldn't match the pattern)
- ```json
  "debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "skipFiles": []
  },
  ```
- ```json
  "debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "skipFiles": [
      "!<node_internals>/**"
    ]
  },
  ```

and not inserting any `debug.javascript.terminalOptions`, VS Code still steps over calls to node internals. It seems like skipping node internal files is a hardcoded setting.

Comment: (fwiw, i used .cc because someone in another question said that worked for them.)

Comment: please [edit] to mention that in your post and include a link to that post.

Comment: it appears that the issue is that the vscode server running on linux does not get the updated settings (from settings.json) when i edit them. i'm going to do a bit more research and will answer the question when i've resolved the issue. (the wsl2 vscode server crashed and, when it restarted, this worked as expected when i set skipFiles to an empty array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for VS Code to honor new settings for

```
"debug.javascript.terminalOptions": {
    "skipFiles": [
      "!<node_internals>/**"
    ]
  }
```

You must execute the `Developer: Reload Window` command. It works that way on standalone linux as well, so it's not WSL2-specific.

`"skipFiles": []` does work as well.