# node internal files do not show up in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

i thought that vscode used to display node's internal files when i stepped into them. for example, now i am seeing `promiseRejectHandler` in the call stack that vscode is displaying, but 1) where the filename is normally shown it says "Unknown source" and 2) the source is not shown. skipFiles is set to an empty array.

this is the case with all node internal modules in the call stack.

this might be related - the function `topLevelDomainCallback` appears in the callstack and vscode shows the file `domain` and, when i hover over that, shows "skipped by skipFiles" (even though skipFiles is an empty array in launch.json). the difference between the two function is that `promiseRejectHandler` is in node's `lib/internal/` directory while `topLevelDomainCallback` is in node's `lib/` directory.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75953724/11107541 (yes, I know that one is also your question)